# App is incompatible with device

Tags: android

I have been developing my app with the Samsung GT-P3113 and now, when I have published the app, I am unable to install it through Google Play Store.

When I check compatible devices through the Developer Console, I am able to see my device, but I am unable to install it from my device due to the following error:

No carrier Samsung GT-P3113

This app requests access to these permissions:

Your location
  approximate location (network-based)
  precise location (GPS and network-based)

Network communication
  full network access
  view network connections

Phone calls
  directly call phone numbers

Storage
  modify or delete the contents of your USB storage

Your accounts
  read Google service configuration

System tools
  test access to protected storage

I am unsure as to what the error might be. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are requesting the `CALL_PHONE` permission. Tablets usually cannot place phone calls. You probably need to add:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

as is described in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions).

Comment: Should I then remove: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE">

Comment: @user3681650: Well, if you are [using `ACTION_CALL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CALL), you need the `CALL_PHONE` permission. You just need to tell Android that you do not absolutely need the device to be a phone, using the `<uses-feature>` element I cited. And, you will need to check at runtime whether or not the device has telephony capability (use `PackageManager` and `hasSystemFeature()`), to determine if your `ACTION_CALL` will work.

Comment: I see, so something like this should work: if (packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY))

Comment: @user3681650: Yes, you can use that to determine, at runtime, if you can use telephony features.